# How perform loop for glmnet in r?

Tags: r

every one
when I use glmnet for individual row I get results, but when use for, while or lapply to loop for every row of matrix get different results except the fist row it was the same, it's problem, please help me.
for individual row use this code

```
fit.cv <- cv.glmnet(xmatrix, ymatrix[1,], family="gaussian", alpha=1, standardize=FALSE, nfolds=5)
lambda <- fit.cv$lambda.min  # Getting the value of lowest value of lambda.
print(lambda)
```

this is while loop

```
while (s<= 5){
  fit.cv <- cv.glmnet(xmatrix, ymatrix[s,], family="gaussian", alpha=1, standardize=FALSE, nfolds=5)$lambda.min
  s<- s+1
  print(fit.cv)
}
```

for loop and lapply the same in results of while loop

Comment: Why would you fit a model to a single row??

Comment: I have matrix contains 5 rows and need perform the model for each row

Comment: Are you sure you shouldn't have `ymatrix[,s]`, i.e., a different column in the `ymatrix`? It doesn't make sense to fit a model for a single row.

Comment: ymatrix by row , contains 5 rows and need perform the model for each row from which